# owin self hosting using soket with web api

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, websocket, owin

I want to open `webSocket` by web api post request.
I tryed to use `HttpContext.Current.AcceptWebSocketRequest` but it didn't work (as you can see in the following example) because `HttpContext.Current` is null in self host.

```
public class ChatController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string username)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.AcceptWebSocketRequest(new ChatWebSocketHandler(username));
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.SwitchingProtocols);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get the current http context without `IIS`?
Or what is the best way to open websocket?

Comment: Host SignalR for WebSockets can be a simpler option.

Comment: I try to use SignalR, but I had trouble with streaming data to specific user and not to all hub users

Comment: SignalR of course supports streaming to a single user, but that would be a new question.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22598567/cant-find-request-getowincontext to get the OwinContext and then accept the WebSocket.

Comment: @Tratcher so how do we accept WebSocketRequest from OwinContext?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41848095/websockets-using-owin